# golang structs or maps in RESTFUL API

Tags: go

When creating a webserver in golang, is there any specific reason why JSON data would be represented as a MAP over a STRUCT or vice versa? ..or is this decision based purely on user preference ?

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about?! What webserver? Where does the JSON come from? You always can Marshall/Unmarshall JSON to/from a struct.

Comment: @0x434D53 Completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this discussion could go either way but the advantages of using structs vs maps are that structs give you an idea of how the schema should look like whereas a map leaves the schema open-ended.

If you use structs, developers who look at the code will have a clear idea of what parameters you're expecting for the API or how the response of the API may look like without digging further into implementation detail. On the other hand if the requests or responses were maps, they would have to look at the implementation detail to see what keys and values are being assigned. Hope this helps!